# how to pass special charcters in url in volley call in android

Tags: java, android, android-volley

```
String description="60% off";

String url_offerAdd=UrlString.url_string+"/offer_Add.php?email="+email+"&desc="+description;

url_offerAdd.replace(" ","%20");

## Heading ##StringRequest  stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url_offerAdd, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
Log.v("response",response);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Offer is submitted succcessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    desc.setText("");
                    tvToDate.setText("");
                    desc.setFocusable(false);
                    tvFromDate.setText("");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.v("response1",error.getMessage());
                }
            });
            MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
```

As  I have taken description 60% off so whenever I am calling php webservice then % symbol is not passing in url  same way none of the special charecter is passing.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code and try

```
String encodeEmail = Uri.encode("your.email@add.com");
String encodeDesc = Uri.encode("description is going here");
String url_offerAdd= UrlString.url_string+"/offer_Add.php?email="+encodeEmail +"&desc="+encodeDesc ;
```

Comment: what would be encodeEmail and encodeDesc?
is it simple string?

Comment: @Bhoomi, yes. I corrected answer, It was by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Encode the URL

```
String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL  exception comes

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method, Working fine for me.

```
  String urll ="http://www.google.com/methodname?Userid="+user_id;

    String url = Uri.parse(urll)
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("Title", title)
            .appendQueryParameter("Desc", description)
            .appendQueryParameter("embededvideo", embededvideo)
            .appendQueryParameter("location", location)
            .appendQueryParameter("perferances", perferances)
            .appendQueryParameter("taguser", taguser)
            .appendQueryParameter("userpostimage", images)
            .build().toString();
```